# D3: draw interactive hover line in multiple line chart for array object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a d3 graph with hover line, the data is fetch from server, which like:

```
data = [
   {
      key: 'series_1',
      values: [
         {
            time: 1420257136216,
            value: 123
         },
         ... ...
      ]
   },
   ... ...
]
```

Here is a quick browse for my codes: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nezasky/vgbm6yut/1/)

**Question**:

I am not able to get the correct y value base on x value (time) from d3 bisector function, the index return from bisector function is not the one I expect.

I have done some search on google, which following this example [d3.js Multi-series line chart interactive](http://bl.ocks.org/DStruths/9c042e3a6b66048b5bd4), the data used for bisector is like:

```
data = [
          {
            series_1: '123',
            series_2: '234',
            time: '1420257136216'
          },
          ....
       ]
```

Do i need to restrict my data like the format above (also sort the data) before I can get the correct return index from d3 bisector function? Or any other way I can achieve it?

Many thanks

Comment: Something like [this](http://phil-pedruco.github.io/examples/coffeeHouse/)?

Comment: @user1614080 yeap. The example you provide is using nvd3. i knew many js libs can solve my problem, but I just want to know how to achieve it. (as i do digging into others code now :P)

Comment: The top chart is vanilla d3 and the second chart is nvd3. The top chart uses `d3.bisector.

Comment: Well, I didn't realise it, coz I saw the nvd3 on the console and the index page, will dig into the code again. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bisect function is wrong for your data.  You have:

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
```

But your property is `time`:

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.time; }).left;
```

You'd then call it (for the fist series) as:

```
bisectDate(data[0].values, someTimeStamp);
```

If your series data is not sorted by time then do:

```
var arr = data[0].values;
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.time - b.time; });
bisectDate(arr, someTimeStamp);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgbm6yut/3/).

Comment: Great thanks. Btw, the wrong define in bisector function just a 'mistake'. When I try to use the bisector before, I didn't use new Date(timeStamp) to get the correct time for bisector index. Now I know!